# Wordpress users redirect

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-login, wordpress-admin

I want to redirect admin other than for wp-admin.
if users(outside admin) write wp-admin, forward to another page.For this, I use 
(I added code to wp-includes/function.php)

```
function restrict_admin_with_redirect() {
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) && ( ! wp_doing_ajax() ) ) {
    wp_safe_redirect( 'aaaa'  );
  ``exit;
    0}}  add_action( 'admin_init', 'restrict_admin_with_redirect', 1 );
```

it works,but While in admin, the problem occurs in the theme or add-ons.
I get an error when I want to add a theme on the theme page.
Error is an unexpected error occured. 
When I delete above function,no problem,Everything is getting better.
Where does the problem come from?

**EDİT:**  I tried another code and it works

```
function custom_blockusers_init() {
  if ( is_user_logged_in() && is_admin() && !current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ) {
    wp_redirect( home_url() );
    exit;
  }
}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_blockusers_init' );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reference [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_url) for filter login URL.

```
add_filter( 'login_url', 'my_login_page', 10, 3 );
function my_login_page( $login_url, $redirect, $force_reauth ) {
    return home_url( '/my-login-page/?redirect_to=' . $redirect );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using current_user_can('manage_options') please use current_user_can('administrator'), this should fix the issue with the permissions granted and you should have it done

Comment: there is same problem.When users write wp-admin,users redirect to where i want(it works),but when I add theme or plugin,it gives error(an expected error)